# Selenium Java finding radio button by aria-label

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a dynamic radio button using the aria-label. Many buttons are dynamic and the ID's change. I receive a

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException:
```

when I run the code.  Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<button class="md-no-style md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="vm.setSelectedZone(zone);" aria-label="Zone 1 SmokeDetector - zone 1"></button>
```

code snippet

```
By temp = By.xpath("//button[@aria-label=\"Zone 1 SmokeDetector - zone 1\" and @type=\"button\"]");
driver.findElement(temp).click();
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the full exception message. It will tell you what element intercepted the click. It's going to be very hard for us to help you here because we can't see the full page. It seems like you've clearly found the button, you just need to figure out what element is intercepting the click and how to deal with it. Find that element and figure out if you can get rid of it, e.g. it's a header so you scroll the page, it's a popup so you dismiss the popup, etc.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <button class="md-no-style md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="vm.setSelectedZone(zone);" aria-label="Zone 1 SmokeDetector - zone 1"></button> is not clickable at point (502, 588). Other element would receive the click: <md-radio-button ng-value="zone.id" aria-label="open" style="margin:0;" id="radio_78" role="radio" aria-checked="false" value="1">...</md-radio-button>
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.112)

Comment: Here is a screen shot

Comment: You need to edit all this extra info into the original question. Also, your screenshot never posted.

Comment: It looks like I am finding the md-label/aria-label with the zone 1 info but it is not clickable so I am getting an error.  I need to find a way to link the text to the button so I can select it.